How to pass a parameter to a SQL Agent Job step that's executing a stored procedure
I am working on a requirement where the database users will have to process files on an ad-hoc basis from time to time. I have a job created for them that executes a stored procedure accepting a value for the process date parameter.
EXEC dbo.p_MyCode @processdate ='2024-09-01';

So, let's say down the line on some random day when the users have to process files for instance December 16th 2024, I want them to be able to execute the job by passing in the date '12-16-2024' and this action might happen sometime in February 15th 2025 per say. This is a correction of data where they reprocess all the data from December 16th until the current date. This is a resource intensive and users don't want to execute the stored procedure on their machine instead have a job where they could run it ad-hoc.
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.p_StartJobWithProcessDate
    @processdate DATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @job_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;
    DECLARE @command NVARCHAR(MAX);

    -- Get the job ID
    SELECT @job_id = job_id
    FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs
    WHERE name = 'MyAdHocJob';

    -- Update the job step with the new process date
    SET @command = N'EXEC p_MyCode @processdate = ''' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @processdate, 23) + '''';

    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_update_jobstep
        @job_id = @job_id,
        @step_id = 1,
        @command = @command;

    -- Start the job
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_id = @job_id;
END;
GO

I'm using this above approach to change the parameter value and run the job on-demand. Is there any other approach to accomplish this using a sql server agent job and being able to change the parameter value dynamically.

fwiw, for historical reasons date literals in SQL Server should use the unseparated 20240901 format, instead of 2024-09-01. But if you're gonna convert it to a varchar anyway, maybe just set the parameter type to varchar from the beginning.

@JoelCoehoorn Got it...This is how 2024-09-01 the vendor company would send us the data.

Also, if it were me, I would make a table with column and one row, and modify the job step to find the process date it needs by checking the table. Then all you have to do is update that table value each time, instead of the job step itself.

I believe your existing solution is the best for your current circumstance.
Here is why:
Jobs are not meant to be interactive, the users will not be prompted to enter the processDate if they start the job.
A stored procedure requiring a parameter is the closest you can get with a solution ONLY in the database.
By having your stored procedure run the job, you solve potential concurrency issues because the sql engine will not allow the same job id to be started if another instance is running, and the sp call will return a message to this effect if your users try.
A few things to note:
Your job should have a variable for your processDate.  This variable should have a default for your scheduled jobs that are not overwriting the value through the sp call.
If you want to reduce the frequency with which the ad hoc reports are run, you could make more jobs with specific date parameters.  eg In your example they run one for the last 90 days, you could make this its own job if it is done all the time so that users do not have to run the ad hoc sp.  You'll have a small library of jobs, but you'll reduce user input error.
Eventually you should probably look to provide a solution to users that doesn't require them to have direct database access, but that seems outside the scope of this specific question.

It seems the goal of this process is calling the p_MyCode stored procedure from an Agent job, where the job sends the correct date to the procedure as an argument.
I suggest modifying the p_MyCode procedure to instead look for the date value in a new table you create for this purpose. Or you may already have some configuration table you can use (possibly using an key/value schema where you would create a new key). Then you only need to update this configuration table, rather than modify the job.
Even better, keep the input argument in the procedure as well, and only check the table if the input value is NULL. Then users or other services can still call the procedure directly with a specific argument, but the Agent job can use the table.
Of course, the downside with this plan is there's a concurrency issue if several users could set the value and run the job at about the same time. But there's a problem for this with your current plan, as well, and this offers improvement where you could use a config table with multiple rows for this value. The procedure can find the right row by also checking an additional column with a value such as a session key or user name.

But I also see this:

This is a resource intensive and users don't want to execute the stored procedure on their machine instead have a job where they could run it ad-hoc.

When you run a stored procedure, it ALWAYS runs on the database server and uses resources there. You may have an app with a user interface that blocks until it finishes, but I promise the resource use is on the database server. In other words, there ought to be a way you can let users just run the procedure directly.
If this is SQL Server Management Studio, that may take up the current query window, but you can open other query windows, or even a separate instance of SSMS, and keep working while a procedure runs.
But I've also seen systems with various mechanism for letting users run procedures, and they aren't always well-designed. Commonly, people will abuse reporting tools for this purpose. They'll create a report that calls into a procedure for the data source, and the reporting tool is not smart enough to  wait for the procedure in an asynchronous way.
If that's the case, running the agent job may be the best you can do. But you can still make the change to use a config table, so the command in the agent job step remains static and never changes.

If you just want to start a process and forget about it, another approach is to use Service Broker. The ProcessDate will be in the message. The following may help get you started:
https://davewentzel.com/content/service-broker-demystified-can-i-model-monologs-yes-you-can/
